# Makefile In Subdirectory Not Working

Tags: makefile

I have a project that is structured with a main directory (project) and a subdirectory (add)  in that main directory.

I want to run a makefile in the main directory, project, which calls another makefile in the 'add' subdirectory.

However, the makefile only works correctly if I call it from the subdirectory manually. If I run $(MAKE) -C add, preprocessor warnings are triggered and the file does not compile. If I run the makefile manually in the subdirectory, the compilation goes fine (as it should. I do not why the warnings are being triggered if I use the makefile from the outside directory).

How can I fix this so that the makefile is called correctly?

Comment: There's no way we can help you with the amount of information provided.  Clearly there is SOMETHING different, but that something is not inherent in make, it's something in your environment which we can't guess at.  The first thing to do is carefully check the compiler lines generated by make when you run it directly in the `add` directory versus when make runs it in the `add` directory and determine what the difference is between them.  Most likely some variable you set in the main makefile is being exported into the sub-make and causing problems.

Comment: You should probably have a look at make documentation and, especially, at the chapter that explains how make variables (compilation flags are frequently passed as make variables) get their value and how sub-make invocations impact the variables.

Comment: As a side note, it is not the best way to achieve what you want usign the recursive `make` invokation. Better use non-recursive approach. I'd recommend to use my template library `prorab` for `GNU make` for that: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md